# What is the relationship between the definition of a well defined operation and a binary operation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, binary-operations

Def.1. A binary operation on a nonempty set $A$ is a map $f:A\times A\to A$ such that

1. $f$ is defined for every pair of elements in $A$, and
2. $f$ uniquely associates each pair of elements in $A$ to some element of $A$.

It seems that the definition of a binary operation includes the definition of a well defined operation (condition 2). But I see other books using the term: Well defined binary operation ! Is there a not well defined binary operation ?

So that just confuses me. What is meant by that ?

Comment: Most likely "well defined binary operation" is used when the author wants to stress that the map is actually a function, which might be helpful when a binary operation is discussed in a setting where a quotient structure defined by some equivalence relation is involved (such as [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22binary+operation%22+%22fundamental+group%22+%22well+defined%22) or [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22binary+operation%22+%22quotient+group%22+%22well+defined%22)).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro So, how is a well defined operation on a set is usually defined ? Dose condition 2 capture this definition ? BTW I'm not familiar with topology.

Comment: *how is a well defined operation on a set is usually defined* --- The same way one "usually defines" any function: by some explicit rule, by recursion, by making reference to some existing function, by the Axiom of Choice, etc.

Comment: I think it does capture it. For a non well-defined function, it could either be that an element is not uniquely mapped or mapped at all, or that the image of an element actually is not contained in the target space. Also, what information does 1. consist that 2. doesn't ?! Or in that spirit, that the word "map" doesn't capture.

Comment: So to prove that an operation is binary, I have to check also that if a=a' and b=b' then a*b=a'*b', right ? (so condition 2 is satisfied ) Or what is another method to check condition 2 ?

Comment: Notice, that in 2. three things are wanted, you mentioned uniqueness. Existence and that the map really stays in A, is also to check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any binary operation is well defined. An author may write "well defined binary operation" when the fact that it is well defined is not obvious. If it weren't, it wouldn't be a binary operation, or even a thing.

Well defined usually means what you said: if $a=a'$ and $b=b'$, then $a*b=a'*b'$. One time when this is not obvious is when rather than using actual equality you're using an equivalence relation and defining the binary operation on elements of the equivalence classes. Then it is well defined on the equivalence classes if it does not depend on the choice of representative. This is the most common case I've seen where the author feels the need to emphasize that it is well defined.